# op. cit. in authoryear-ibid

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies

I use `biblatex` with the `authoryear-ibid` style, that is citations look like this: **(Author 2019)**, and like this: **(ibid.)** when the same reference is cited several times in a row.

What I want is the following: when I cite a reference that has already been cited before, but *not just before*, I would like the citation to be: **(Author, op. cit.)**. I can't find out how to do it, does anybody have a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The style `authoryear-ibid` does not stand to gain a lot from using *op. cit.*: a year is hardly longer than 'op. cit.' and it has the huge advantage of being a unique and somewhat informative label.

But it is of course possible to modify `authoryear-ibid` a bit to include *op. cit.*. Compare the redefinition below with [the original in `authoryear-ibid.cbx`](https://github.com/plk/biblatex/blob/c71ee542a3301b7a1e8bfc4420f581a2207ffa13/tex/latex/biblatex/cbx/authoryear-ibid.cbx#L18-L29). The relevant change consists in replacing

```
   \usebibmacro{cite:labeldate+extradate}
```

with

```
    \ifopcit
      {\usebibmacro{cite:opcit}}
      {\usebibmacro{cite:labeldate+extradate}}
```

The definition of `cite:opcit` is a straightforward copy from [`verbose-trad1.cbx`](https://github.com/plk/biblatex/blob/c71ee542a3301b7a1e8bfc4420f581a2207ffa13/tex/latex/biblatex/cbx/verbose-trad1.cbx#L147-L148). Furthermore, `biblatex` must be loaded with the option `opcittracker=context,`.

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[style=authoryear-ibid, opcittracker=context, backend=biber]{biblatex}

\newbibmacro*{cite:opcit}{%
  \printtext[bibhyperlink]{\bibstring[\mkibid]{opcit}}}

\renewbibmacro*{cite}{%
  \global\boolfalse{cbx:loccit}%
  \iffieldundef{shorthand}
    {\ifthenelse{\ifciteibid\AND\NOT\iffirstonpage}
       {\usebibmacro{cite:ibid}}
       {\ifthenelse{\ifnameundef{labelname}\OR\iffieldundef{labelyear}}
          {\usebibmacro{cite:label}%
           \setunit{\printdelim{nonameyeardelim}}}
          {\printnames{labelname}%
           \setunit{\printdelim{nameyeardelim}}}%
        \ifopcit
          {\usebibmacro{cite:opcit}}
          {\usebibmacro{cite:labeldate+extradate}}}}
    {\usebibmacro{cite:shorthand}}}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}


\begin{document}
\cite{sigfridsson}

\cite{knuth:ct:a}

\cite{sigfridsson}

\cite{knuth:ct:a}

\cite{worman}

\cite{knuth:ct:b}

\cite{worman}

\cite{knuth:ct:b}

\cite{sigfridsson}

\cite{sigfridsson}


\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

gives

[image: Sigfridsson and Ryde 1998//Knuth 1984//Sigfridsson and Ryde op. cit.//Knuth op. cit.//Worman 2002//Knuth 1986//Worman op. cit.//Knuth op. cit.//Sigfridsson and Ryde op. cit.//ibid.]

I have severe doubts that this is clearer than the normal output from `authoryear-ibid`.

Especially the fact that 'Knuth op. cit.' might refer to `knuth:ct:a` or `knuth:ct:b` requires the reader to pay much closer attention to previous citations than probably necessary.

---

If you want to restrict *op. cit.* to authors with only a single work to avoid confusion, you should load `biblatex` with the option `singletitle` and replace `\ifopcit` in the above with

```
        \ifthenelse{\ifopcit\AND\ifsingletitle}
```

Then the MWE produces

[image: Sigfridsson and Ryde 1998//Knuth 1984//Sigfridsson and Ryde op. cit.//Knuth 1984//Worman 2002//Knuth 1986//Worman op. cit.//Knuth 1986//Sigfridsson and Ryde op. cit.//ibid.]

Ambiguities are avoided here, but you get a weird mixture of 'op. cit.' and non-'op. cit.' citations.